# I am not able to view the file in program of text to handwriting

Tags: python, file, photo, handwriting-recognition, handwriting

Please help, i am beginner in python.
The code i used for text to handwriting is this

```
import pywhatkit as pw

txt = """ What is Lorem Ipsum? """

pw.text_to_handwriting(txt,"img2.png",[0,0,138])
pw.text_to_handwriting(txt)
print("END")
```

When i am opening the png it is showing "**It appears that we don't support this file format**"
I tried jpg, jpeg as well.

[The error -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyPNK.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AthulMuralidhar Sir I have inserted the image of error also. Please click on "The error" . I tried updating photos , put different versions of code too. After the output image is created , it is showing what i told.

Comment: hey, you could probably type it out - makes the question succinct (at least that's what I meant by my comment :) )